# WordPress MU Domain Mapping plugin with new subdirectory

Tags: wordpress, dns, mapping

My client site is using WordPress MU Domain Mapping plugin for multisite. I have created new standalone WordPress for the site in a subdirectory, both under same hosting and same domain name.

This is existing site
http://www.oldsite.com
This is new wordpress site
http://www.oldsite.com/new

May I know how can I redirect the existing site to /new?

Can I just change the Siteurl to http://www.oldsite.com/new on existing WordPress MU Domain Mapping setting, so it can point to my new directory, Is that how it works?

Thanks for your help
Wayne

Answer (score 1):

You have to change your site URL.
You have to do like this for your new site URL: http://www.newsite.oldsite.com in WordPress MU Domain mapping setting.